# How to answer automatically (Y/N) when prompt?

Tags: batch-file

My `click.bat` file:

```
:main
@start /wait cmd.exe -/c ""C:\Users\MY_USER_NAME\Desktop\2.bat" "
goto :main
```

My `2.bat` file:

```
@echo off
echo Hello World!
@pause
```

I am clicking `Click.bat` and they are both opening (no problem in here).

After that I am closing the Hello World! prompt (`2.bat`).

and prompt of the `Click.bat`, ask me `^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?`

*I want to auto answer at here (as `N`)*.

(When the answer is `N`, `2.bat` opening again like as I want).

[image: First]
[image: Second]
[image: Third]

Comment: How are you *closing the Hello World! prompt(2.bat)*?

Comment: @KenWhite   Manually

Comment: *Manually* does not answer the question I asked. **How specifically are you closing 2.bat**?  *Manually* has no meaning.

Comment: So you ignored my question and instead posted three images that say the same thing as your text did before?

Comment: @KenWhite no no. i am closing the 2.bat with left click. Like that:  
https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/e/e6/Close-Windows-Step-23-Version-3.jpg/aid3728596-v4-728px-Close-Windows-Step-23-Version-3.jpg

Comment: Why not replace the `@pause` in the second bat with `timeout 5>nul` it will timeout for 5 seconds so you can see result of the echo then timeout and exit.

Comment: I suggest to modify last line of `2.bat` to `@if /I not "%~1" == "/NoWait" pause` and replace second line of `click.bat` by `call "%UserProfile%\Desktop\2.bat" /NoWait` and your problem should be solved. It is not possible to answer the prompt output by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file with the batch file itself because of batch file execution is halted by `cmd.exe` at this point. So it is not possible to add code to answer the prompt as this code is not executed by `cmd.exe` on prompting the user if the batch file execution should be really terminated without finishing batch execution.

Comment: Why don't you *Press any key to continue* as prompted by the `pause` command? Clicking the **X** is nothing but aborting the running batch file as if you would press Ctrl+C/Ctrl+Break, which is transferred from the sub-script to the main script, which in turn throwns the *Y/N* prompt...

Comment: (Part of 1/3 comment) @Mofi doesn't worked. I need more explain myself. I dont need to fake 2.bat. it's just an example. I am using this pyhton script: [lynda-dl
](https://github.com/r0oth3x49/lynda-dl) for downloading Lynda courses. it is mostly crashes when running. (It's hard to write for every time:  [like this](https://i.imgur.com/eBBj5ax.png)) 

I prepared .bat file for this job [real 2.bat (not Hello World)]. My goal is 2.bat auto restarts when its(2.bat) crashed.

Comment: (Part of 2/3 comment) @GerhardBarnard I found a perfect program for making this: [link](https://www.ghacks.net/2011/12/31/monitor-a-process-to-restart-it-automatically-on-exit/) . But its supports only **1** process at same time. I need **4** process at same time. **That's all I want**.

Comment: (Part of 3/3 comment) @aschipfl (I mentioned all of you like this. because user mention limit.) 


I can make a little video if I couldn't explain myself **/aschipfl /GerhardBarnard /Mofi**

Comment: I recommend to find out the reason for the unexpected terminations of the Python script on downloading a course instead of working around this issue. The Python script source is available as open source and so can be improved by everyone with Python script code writing skills. Issues can be reported as it can be read on main page of this project. So report the issues you see on using this script and ask for fixes. Working around the issues is definitely not the right approach in this case.

Comment: @Mofi
Yeah, you're right. I will report the issue. Thank you so much for clear answers. I am very pleased : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Mofi that addressing the real issue is always better than to work around it, but sometimes this isn't possible or you need a quicker solution.

Instead of passively waiting, until the second process finishes, just actively watch it. If it isn't alive anymore, restart it. That way, it doesn't matter, *how* the second process finishes/exits/crashes:

**test1.bat**

```
@echo off
:main
if exist MyCommand.flag goto :eof
start test2.bat
:wait
timeout 1 >nul
tasklist /fi "Windowtitle eq MyCommand"|find "cmd.exe" >nul || @goto :main
goto :wait
```

**test2.bat**

```
@echo off
title MyCommand
echo Hello World!
@pause
break>MyCommand.flag
```

You don't have to `start cmd /c`, because `start` alone already starts a new cmd process. Give the process a unique title, so you can check, if it is still running.

`||` works as "if previous command (`find`) fails then"
`find` is neccessary, because `tasklist` does not provide a helpful errorlevel.

Note: you also need a method to stop, when the second process finishes its task.
`Test2.bat` writes an empty file when finished. Obviously the file wouldn't be created, when the process crashes before (or is forcefully terminated).
`test1.bat` simply checks for the existence of the file before restarting the second process.

Comment: **Loop is working perfect. Omg you're amazing. I had no hope. Worked like a charm. God bless you** :)
I made a video for my situation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwi0aBqdc5I